# Restkit: How to get and map data from multiple source

Tags: ios, restkit, tastypie

I'm currently working on iOS Application with RestKit 0.20 to access data from Tastypie API.

And I am trying to get feeds data from URL like this

```
/api/v2/feed/?format=json
```

Then I will get array of feeds as below.

```
{
  "meta": {
    "limit": 20,
    "next": null,
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 2
  },
  "objects": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "info": "This is my first post",
      "pub_date": "2013-02-03T15:59:33.311000",
      "user": "/api/v2/user/1/",
      "resource_uri": "/api/v2/feed/1/"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "info": "second post, yeah",
      "pub_date": "2013-02-03T16:00:09.350000",
      "user": "/api/v2/user/1/",
      "resource_uri": "/api/v2/feed/2/"
    }
  ]
}
```

if I want to fetch more data about user which Tastypie send it as url like a foreign key  `"user": "/api/v2/user/1/"`, do I have to nested call objectRequestOperation.

I'm confusing because I'm using block to callback when data is successful loaded. So is there any better way than requesting user data again for each feed after requesting feed complete.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define in the Feed resource :

```
user = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, full=True)
```

More info in the tastypie doc http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html

Why Resource URIs?
Resource URIs play a heavy role in how Tastypie delivers data. This can seem very different from other solutions which simply inline related data. Though Tastypie can inline data like that (using full=True on the field with the relation), the default is to provide URIs.

URIs are useful because it results in smaller payloads, letting you fetch only the data that is important to you. You can imagine an instance where an object has thousands of related items that you may not be interested in.

URIs are also very cache-able, because the data at each endpoint is less likely to frequently change.

And URIs encourage proper use of each endpoint to display the data that endpoint covers.

Ideology aside, you should use whatever suits you. If you prefer fewer requests & fewer endpoints, use of full=True is available, but be aware of the consequences of each approach.

Comment: Is it possible to send selective inline data, not all of it?